# IIS Express: localhost/App_1 instead of localhost/App

Tags: iis-7, iis-express

I downloaded the Web application code from TFS 2010. The solution file consist of the Project and EndProject with Websiteproperties to settings with the applicatoin name as localhost/App.
So, when I opened the solution it creates a application on IIS as localhost/App

I downloaded the same application code from different branch (different version)it consist the same solution script and it created a new application on IIS as localhost/App1

Currently I am using only the second version, I removed the first application from my local, I removed all IIS application. When opening the second code base it still creating the application as localhost/App1 on IIS.

It is trying to overwrite the script in solution file as well. 
I could not get the setting that is causing this.!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the properties on the second project, as the 1st project had already reserved the IIS application name the second project will have added a 1 to the App Name. VS will have then updated the properties to reflect that another solution had reserved the app name.